# Aprendendo a programar - IDE PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Estou aprendendo a programar a escolhi a linguagem Python e estou usando o VScode
Eu baixei o vscod. Quando eu aperto "f5" para rodar o código, ele da erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso fazer, para que abra um "cmd" que eu possa digitar e testar os códigos?

Comment: [![Exemplo em imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17EdT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17EdT.png)para que o codigo possa rodar clique o lado direito do mouse no workspace e selecione a opcao **Run python file in terminal**

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro é comum, faltou colocar a linha

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Essa deve ser a primeira linha, você deve colocá-la em todos os arquivos `.py` que você criar com esse editor.

O motivo é que o seu editor usa essa codificação para salvar os arquivos, portanto, você deve indicar isso ao python colocando essa informação no começo do arquivo.

Você pode clicar no link que tem na própria mensagem de erro pra mais informações:

```
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
```